# PayPal button using Sandbox not showing

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm trying to get a simple "Buy Now" button to appear on my page, but I can't get it to appear, here's my code:

```
<script>
    data-amount="3.00" 
    data-name="MyActivity" 
    data-button="buynow" src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=MERCHANT_ID"
</script>
<form class="paypal-button" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_top" style="opacity: 1;">
<input type="button" value="buy">
</form>
```

In my code the merchant ID is there I've just taken out for this.

Answer (score 2):

Those should all be attributes of the script tag, not code within the tag... like so...

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=MERCHANT_ID"
    data-amount="3.00" 
    data-name="MyActivity" 
    data-button="buynow">
</script>
```

You'll need to download the js file and have it on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to the page you have this set up on that you can provide?  Verify, that have you save and post your code to your page that your editor is not stripping out some of the code.  Go to the web page and view the source of the page and make sure its the same as what you are entering in.  I see a button, when I use your code on an HTML page.

Comment: No it's all local on my machine. Yeah I added that button in because I thought that may have been what you needed to add or if the JavaScript generated it for you. It's all there when I view source, what could I be missing? or doing wrong?

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing the entire code for your page.  The code you provided works by itself.  The only other issues I have seen with buttons not showing up in the past, was due to cascading style sheets chaing the button size so small that it was not visible.  You might try commenting your style sheets out, and see if this makes a difference.  Keep in mind your page will layed out completely different while they are commented out, but this will help you to confirm that they are or are not the cause of the issue.  Also make sure all of your tages are open and closed properly.

Comment: That's the only code? Do I need some styles too? That code is just in a test file by it self

Comment: The code is working fine by itself, when I test it.  So something has to be causing the issue on the page that it is getting populated on to within your site.  Is there a particular reason that you are using a script to set some of the values, as opposed to just using HTML code similar to how the button is created from within the PayPal account.  If there isn't a reason your specifically using a script, try using the HTML code that is generated when creating a button and see if this makes a difference.